# How to make String class iterable? Possible?

Tags: java

How can I make this work in java?

```
String p = "Hello";

for(char i: p)
    System.out.print(i);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do:

```
for (char i: p.toCharArray())
    System.out.print(i);
```

Answer (score 5):

Strings are *not* [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) in Java (as opposed to in Python, for instance), but you can loop over their internal character arrays:

```
for (char i : p.toCharArray())
    System.out.print(i);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Equally very helpful

Answer (score 1):

I totally misunderstood the question at first. If you just want to iterate over the String , use the charArray method as others answered. But if you also want to remove characters and append , then use a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

**-** What you mean by make the `String` iterable, its only possible by converting it into `char` array.

**-** If you want to access characters within the `String` directly you can use `chatAt()` method.

**-** But if you want to make it `iterable` then go for `toCharArray()` method

**Eg:**

```
char[] arr = p.toCharArray();

for (char i: arr){

       System.out.print(i);

 }
```